# Wordpress top menu link to show/hide div

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I want to have one of my links on the top menu of my wordpress template show a hidden div on the top of the page when clicked. How could I do this with a css class or url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would use the jQuery toggleClass function, which would also require additional CSS class.

```
$('.button').on('click', function (e) {
    $('div').toggleClass("show");
});
```

CSS:

```
div {
    display: none;
}

div.show {
    display: block;
}
```

This is very basic and would only make it show and hide, you can add some transitions to it to make it looks smoothers or use the slideToggle() function instead.

Comment: This is exactly what I need! Thank you! Would I put this function in the header.php or in the functions.php?

Comment: You would put it in your main JS file wherever that maybe - can you mark this answer with correct if it is appropriate